# Materialize footer not going to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer, materialize

Is there a way to keep the footer at the bottom of the page, even if there isn't a lot of content? I followed the instructions on the Materialize page and have all my HTML between `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<footer>` tags. I haven't applied any of my own CSS to the footer at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="/" class="brand-logo">Some Title <i class="material-icons left hide-on-med-and-down">apps</i></a>
        <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="">Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li id="timer-tab"><a href="">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li id="stats-tab"><a href="">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li id="graphs-tab"><a href="">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="" data-activates="dropdown" class="dropdown-button">Tab 4<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Some Title</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col l2 offset-l2 s6">
          <h6>About</h6>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">Suggestions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l2 s6">
          <h6>Developer</h6>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">Source</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">Contribute</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="grey-text text-lighten-3">API Docs</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">Made by <a href="">Me </a></div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: can I have your css?

Comment: Sure, but I didn't really do much CSS. I'm just using materialize.min.css and [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5cbb294178956524f309).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/footer.html#sticky-footer): the below rules must be added to your css for getting the sticky footer:

```
 body {
     display: flex;
     min-height: 100vh;
     flex-direction: column;
 }
 main {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
 }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtnnhkaf/)

Comment: The fiddle helped. My problems was to be using <main> inside the container, and the footer inside main.

Comment: @Lucky can u provide me a demo?

Comment: For some reason I have the right HTML structure and I use the exact CSS in your example, but still the footer won't set to bottom of page!?

Answer (score 13):

Just to add, Alex answer works perfectly since you have this structure:

```
<body>
<!-- Header content -->
<main>Page Content</main>
<!-- Footer content --> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add this style: **position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;** at the footer element.

For example:

```
<footer class="page-footer" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;">
    ...
</footer>
```

Comment: I would recommend Alex's answer for someone using Materialize CSS, as opposed to fixed positioning.  On very short viewports, the fixed position approach can completely obscure your content.  By using the flex container, the height of the footer is taken into account to the overall height of the page, and keeps it below the content.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is using react with materialize, I had the same problem caused by the root `div` so instead of assigning the body with display flex change that to

```
#root {
         display: flex;
         min-height: 100vh;
         flex-direction: column;
       }
```

The root is the immediate parent.

Answer (score 1):

I also use the correct materialize format according to: https://materializecss.com/footer.html

But it in IE browser. It is not working properly, but, if you also add the following style: style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;"   it will be ok.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>

        <main>
        </main>
        
        <footer style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;">
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```